# Possible to define custom form validation callbacks in the global scope in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

After reading the form validation doc:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

I am led to believe that all custom form validation callbacks must be defined inside a controller. I can think of several instances where a function like this should instead be defined in a helper file, and therefore loaded into the global namespace, per CI design. Is this possible? It seems like CI has some built-in restrictions like this that are very difficult to change or work around.

Comment: Validation should always be done in the controller, not a helper file. In what instance would you need validation to be done in a helper file? Helper's are primarily for basic functions that don't rely on any part of Codeigniter (although you can still use Codeigniter functions inside helpers). Such as a function for formatting date and time across your website, that would be a situation to use a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well think of it this way - if the callback is only going to be called when you are validating your form - then it doesn't need to be 'global' in any way.

there are some people who are committed to doing validation in a controller and therefore they advocate having 'fat controllers' . my suggestion is to do your form validation in a model. one advantage is that if you need to call the form validation from different places - which is what you are implying by asking about a helper - you can call the validation very easily from any of your controllers (or other models). so then you do not need to load a separate helper file - and the name of the model and the method should make it clear what is being validated.

the other advantage is that if you change or update your form and the validation and callback - it all happens in the model. the controller code does not change, which again is helpful if you are calling this validation from different places.

here is another response you might find helpful: 
[Codeigniter Form Validation in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861401/codeigniter-form-validation-in-model/20862630#20862630)

Answer (score 3):

You actually can define "global" validation rules yourself. Just extend the CI_Form_Validation class.

`class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {`

This class must go in your application/libraries folder. Add your validation function there and CI will pick up your version of the class. You do not need to add the callback_ prefix on the rules in this case.

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('field', 'Field', 'your_function');`

Comment: And in the actual `your_function()` set the error message with `$this->set_message('your_function', 'Your error message.')`. _Not_ `$this->form_validation->set_rules(...`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that the ci has come out with several core function that you can't change.

in your cases you need to :

1. you need to include the ci core validation class to your helper
2. then create the object to use it.